# Associative arrays in Node JS for a list of subscribers

Tags: node.js, associative-array

I need to create, in Node JS, a **list of "subscribers"** which will provide a **device** *(string)* for which they want to receive notifications when there is new data from, and the **IP and Port** *(both strings)* to forward the data. The **list should be unique**; i.e., there should only be just one combination of (device, IP, Port) in the list. I also need to efficiently get a sub-list of IP/Port of subscribers when data come from a device, to know where to forward the data to.

In other languages, I was using Associative Arrays for this (with Unique index), so using something like this;

```
subscribers[device] = (IP,Port)
```

solved the problem. So when new data comes from a **device**, filtering the array with the device index, gives me a **list of subscribers** to forward the data to.

I'm wondering what is the best approach to implement this in Node JS. I was looking at Arrays, but I don't find Associative Arrays, and I'm not sure if another way would be a better approach...

Thanks in advance
Gus

Comment: Actually, I guess my description above is not completely accurate.. A "device" may have multiple subscribers (IP/Port) and a "Subscriber" may subscribe to multiple "devices". What it needs to be unique is a combination of device/IP/Port in the list of subscribers...Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution that works for your use case is using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of strings, where you concat the IP address and port:

```js
const subscribers = new Map<string, Set<string>>();

function addSubscriber(device: string, ip: string, port: number) {
    let set = subscribers.get(device);
    if (!set) {
        set = new Set<string>();
        subscribers.set(device, set);
    }
    // Lowercase in case your IP is an IPv6 and can have random upper/lower case
    set.add(`${ip.toLowerCase()}:${port}`);
}

const splitCombo = (combo: string): [string, number] => {
    const split = combo.split(':');
    return [split[0], parseInt(split[1])];
};

function getSubscribers(device: string): [ip: string, port: number][] {
    const set = subscribers.get(device);
    if (!set) return [];
    return Array.from(set).map(splitCombo);
}
```

*written in TypeScript to show you the types*

Otherwise you'd need to create your own variant of an associated map/list. Still possible and maybe a lot of fun, but also a lot more complex than this simple variant. E.g. replace the `Set<string>` with a `[string, number][]` array, but then you'd have to manually check when adding a new pair if that pair is already present. Using a `Set<string>`, the `.add` will quite efficiently take care of this for you.